# How to remove line between discontinuities in R

Tags: r

I want to plot the following piecewise function in R: f(x)=x if x<=1/2, f(x)=x-1 if x>1/2. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to remove the line joining the two points between the discontinuity at x=1/2. My code is below:

```
x<-seq(0,1,1/255)
fx<-ifelse(x<=1/2,x,x-1)
plot(x,fx,ylim=c(-1,1),type='l')
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Is there a way to remove only the line joining those two points, but keep everything else? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to do more than just plot the two pieces? 
`x1<-seq(0,1/2,1/255);
fx1<-x1;
x2<-seq(1/2,1,1/255);
fx2<-x2-1;
plot(x1,fx1,ylim=c(-1,1),xlim=c(0,1), type='l');
lines(x2, fx2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `curve`

```
plot(1, ylim=c(-1,1), xlim = c(0, 1), type = "n")
curve(x + 0, from = 0, to = 1/2, add = TRUE)
curve(x - 1, from = 1/2, to = 1, add = TRUE)
```

[image]